# How to pass salary data to each salesperson in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble understanding how to get the information in my array to print for a comparison.  I need to compare salesperson[0]'s and salesperson[1]'s total annual compensation and cannot figure out how to pass each salesperson's compensation.  Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import tools for scanner useage
import java.util.InputMismatchException;//import tools for try-catch
import java.text.DecimalFormat;//format percentages

public class AnnualCompensationCalculator 
{

    //main method begins    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //create object to assign greeting
        AnnCompGreet myGreeting = new AnnCompGreet();

        // call greeting
        myGreeting.displayMessage();

        //object to call table
        AnnCompTable myTable = new AnnCompTable();

        //object to call formatting for percentages
        DecimalFormat percent = new DecimalFormat("#0%");

        //variable for boolean answer to display table
        boolean bool = true;

        /**
         * next few lines determine whether or not 
         * to display the compensation table
        */ 
        do 
        {
            try 
            {
                //ask user if they want to display compensation table
                System.out.print("Would you like to see compensation table?"
                        + "  Enter: True/False  ");

                //create scanner to obtain bool
                Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
                boolean boolAnswer = answer.nextBoolean();

                //this will display the table
                if (boolAnswer == true) 
                {
                    myTable.displayTable();

                } //this will display message when table is not displayed
                else if (boolAnswer == false) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Then let us continue!");
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, the table"
                                    + " will not be displayed.");
            }

        } while (!bool);

        final double salary = 100000.00;//fixed variable
        double numberSales;//hold place of sales variable
        double annualSalary;//hold place of total annual salary
        int people;//used for array to gather salesperson info


        //create Commission object
        Commission number = new Commission();

        //create scanner for sales info
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //used to determine how many salespeople will be entered for array
        System.out.print("How many Sales people are you entering? ");
        people = keyboard.nextInt();

        //array for sales people information
        String[]SalespersonName = new String[people];

        //loops array
        for(int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {

            //requests salesperson's name
            System.out.print("Enter name of salesperson "
                    + "number " + (i+1) + ": ");
            SalespersonName[i] = keyboard.next();

            do
            {                    
                //next two lines used to obtain annual sales
                System.out.print("Enter " + SalespersonName[i]
                        + "'s annual sales: "
                                    + "$");
                numberSales = keyboard.nextDouble();

                //set annual sales and commission rate
                number.set(numberSales, 0.0);


                //conditional statements to determin annual sales
                if (numberSales <= 96000) 
                {
                    //displays base commission rate
                    System.out.println("Base Commission rate is: 5%.");

                    //displays current commission rate
                    System.out.println(SalespersonName[i] + "'s "
                                        + "commission rate is:  "
                                        + percent.format(number.getRate()));

                    //displays message for not reaching target sales
                    System.out.println("Sorry you have not reached your "
                                        + "target of $96,000.");
                    //equation to calculate total annual compensation
                    annualSalary = salary + number.getSalesCommission();

                    //displays salary with no commissions
                    System.out.printf(SalespersonName[i] 
                                       + "'s annual compensation "
                                        + "is:  $%,.2f \n", annualSalary);
                }
                else 
                {
                    //displays base commission rate
                    System.out.println("Base commission rate is: 5%.");

                    //displays current commission rate for salesperson
                    System.out.println(SalespersonName[i] 
                                        + "'s commission rate is "
                                        + percent.format(number.getRate()));

                    //displays commissions earned
                    System.out.printf(SalespersonName[i] 
                                       + "'s total commission is: "
                                    + "$%,.2f \n", number.getSalesCommission());

                    //equation to calculate total annual compensation
                    annualSalary = salary + number.getSalesCommission();

                    //displays total annual compensation
                    System.out.print(SalespersonName[i] 
                            + "'s annual compensation is ");
                    System.out.printf("$%,.2f \n", annualSalary);
                }
            }while (i == people);
        }     
        for(int i = 0; i < people; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(SalespersonName[i]);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your do-while loop will is unnecessary because the while condition will never be met; it will always be entered one time.

Comment: may be sql group by having aggregate function will work better. just like you i also don't understand the code

Comment: okay do-while can be deleted, thanks for that advice, I will do that, but with or without the do-while I still do not understand how to pass the annual salary.  I have tried a nesting (multidimensional array) and that did not work either, maybe it is just because I am not understanding how to set up the multidimensional array, I really do not know.

Comment: zod, unfortunately the code must be in Java.  I have been researching how to do multidimensional arrays for the past few days and have yet to understand how to get all the information passed appropriately.

Comment: First off, change the name of the Commission variable, it's very confusing. //create Commission object
        Commission commission = new Commission(); ... second, you are reusing the same object and always setting the commission rate to 0, right?  You say here : System.out.println("Base commission rate is: 5%."); but you never change the Commission object to reflect that rate.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I guess I should have also added in my other files.  There is a base commission rate of 5% but yes it gets set to 0 and is incremented based on total sales. Sales and commission rates are being passed from another class.

Answer (score 0):

you could make `salesPerson` an object with a local variable `compensation`

that way you can just compare `saleperson[0].compensation > saleperson[1].compensation`

edit: you would also include `name` and possibly do the calculations for commission here as well

Comment: Do you mean to make a salesPerson class file and call the variables into the array?

Comment: make a salesPerson class file with variables `name` and `compensation` and then make the array an array of salesPersons. that way when you retrieve one of the salesPersons you can easily retrieve their name and information

Comment: Would it work if I just copied and pasted my current information for salesperson and compensation into the new file?  I had considered trying to do it this way, but wasn't sure how well it would work.  I will try it after dinner and see if I can make it work.  Thank you.